# Highlight word in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

So I think I found the answer to my question [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399655/microsoft-word-macro-for-highlighting-multiple-words) But when I copied and pasted the VBA code I get an error of "Compile error: Argument not optional" on the "With range.Find" line.

```
Sub HighlightWords2()

Dim range As range
Dim i As Long
Dim TargetList

TargetList = Array("words") 'put list of terms to find here

For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)

Set range = ActiveDocument.range

With range.Find
.Text = TargetList(i)
.Format = True
.MatchCase = True
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False

Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Loop
End With
Next
End Sub
```

The OP was happy with his result and looking at the code I don't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Please show the rest of the lines in your `With` block.

Comment: Word != Excel, record an Excel Macro & examine the generated source.

Comment: As @Alex said - Excel won't have things such as `MatchWholeWord` or `MatchSoundsLike`.  You need to think in Excel, not Word.

Comment: Oh wow... thanks Alex, I totally missed that!

Comment: Good place to start is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759962/change-font-color-for-specific-char-in-a-cell-range)

Answer (score 1):

After I messed up my original post by looking at Word VBA code and no Excel I found an answer and then modified it to fit what I was looking for below is the code I used and it works for me. Thanks for all the other answers!

```
Sub HIGHLIGHTER()
Dim sPos As Long, sLen As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim findMe As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim SearchArray

SearchArray = Array("DEMENTIA", "SENILE", "ALZHEIMERS", "ALZHIEMERS", "WANDERING", "WANDER", "DEMENT")

For t = 0 To UBound(SearchArray)

    Set rng = Range("N2:N10000")
    findMe = SearchArray(t)

    For Each rng In rng
        With rng
            If rng.Value Like "*" & findMe & "*" Then
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    For i = 1 To Len(rng.Value)
                        sPos = InStr(i, rng.Value, findMe)
                        sLen = Len(findMe)

                        If (sPos <> 0) Then
                            rng.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                            rng.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Bold = True
                            i = sPos + Len(findMe) - 1
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next rng

Next t
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you're trying to do:

```
Sub HighlightWords2()

Dim range As range
Dim i As Long

Dim TargetList(3)

TargetList(0) = "SearchTerm1"
TargetList(1) = "SearchTerm2"
TargetList(2) = "SearchTerm3"
TargetList(3) = "SearchTerm4"

For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)

    Set range = ActiveSheet.Cells

    With range
        Set c = .Find(TargetList(i), lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                c.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
    End With

Next i

End Sub
```