# Microsoft Word macro for highlighting 500+ words, with no limit to TargetList

Tags: macros

I've tried using the code shared in [this stackoverflow thread about creating a macro that highlights specific words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399655/microsoft-word-macro-for-highlighting-multiple-words), and that code works for up to 68 words and phrases, but then it seems like I reach a limit and it won't allow me to enter additional terms. I need to be able to search for and highlight 500+ terms.

Is there normally a limit to search terms? Or is there a way for me to refer the macro to a separate document that contains all the words I want it to identify, as opposed to entering each term into the code? Thanks very much for any guidance.

I have already tried this code with up to 68 targets, at which point the code stops letting me enter new terms:

```
Sub HighlightTargets()
'
' HighlightTargets Macro
'
'
Dim range As range
Dim i As Long
Dim TargetList

TargetList = Array("target 1", "target 2", "target 3", ... "target 68")
For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)

Set range = ActiveDocument.range

With range.Find
.Text = TargetList(i)
.Format = True
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False

Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

Loop

End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow :) You might improve your question slightly by naming the link something other than 'here'. Perhaps a short phrase that explains where the link leads? In your case you might change it to 'in this other stackoverflow question'. Also, consider documenting what you've already tried. this can give the potential answerer more context.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tips, jaydel!